# One Action Listnener for an array of buttons inside an array of panels

Tags: arrays, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to make an action listener for a gird of buttons. I created the grid by making a 3 by 3 grid of panels that each has a 3 by 3 grid of buttons in them. I need a way to make the action listener tell which button was pressed. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GameBoardDisplayTest {

    protected JFrame gameBoardFrame = new JFrame();
    protected JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[9];
    protected JPanel[] panelArray = new JPanel[9];
    protected String playerXName;
    protected String playerOName;
    protected JPanel gameStatePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));


    public GameBoardDisplayTest(String player1, String player2){

        playerXName = player1;
        playerOName = player2;

        gameBoardFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameBoardFrame.setSize(1000,1000);
        gameBoardFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gameBoardFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameBoardFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));

        for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++){
            panelArray[i] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
            }

        for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j != 9; j++){
                buttonArray[j] = new JButton("-");
                    buttonArray[j].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
                panelArray[i].add(buttonArray[j]);
                }
            }


        for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++){

            gameBoardFrame.add(panelArray[i]);

    }    

        gameStatePanel.add(new JLabel("Current Turn's Player"));
        gameStatePanel.add(new JLabel("Current Grid"));
        gameStatePanel.add(new JLabel("Game Start"));


        gameBoardFrame.add(new JLabel("X: " + playerXName));
    gameBoardFrame.add(gameStatePanel);
        gameBoardFrame.add(new JLabel("O: " + playerOName));

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getSource());
        }
    }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    String firstPlayerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the first player: ");

    String secondPlayerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the second player: ");


    GameBoardDisplayTest gridDisplay = new GameBoardDisplayTest(firstPlayerName,secondPlayerName);
}

}
```

Comment: Give them variable references, individually. Unless they contain different text (which all yours are `-`), you should use a variable reference.

Comment: Any advice on how to do that without manually creating 81 variables?

Comment: What I don't get is how do you differentiate between the actions of the buttons if all contain the same text `"-"`? If they had different text, you could call them by text. So what is it you're actually trying to accomplish with these buttons?

Comment: I'm trying to create an Ultimate Tic Tac Toe board. When the button is clicked, I want to send the location of the button to an object I didn't include here and change text inside to an X or an O.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I'm a bit confused as how you think you have 81 buttons. Your array only has 9 buttons. So my answer may not be fully correct for you situation, but it's a way toward solving your question

Answer (score 1):

You can loop again in the actionPerformed.

```
int buttonLocation;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++){
        if (e.getSource() == buttonArray[i])
            buttonLocation = i;
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to how you think you have 81 buttons. Your array only has 9 buttons. So my answer may not be fully correct for you situation, but it's a way toward solving your question. Suggestion, You may want to have a 2D array of JButtons, as it makes more sense, getting the grid index for a tic tac toe board